# How to create table in Pdf with functionality of rowspan and colspan in IOS

Tags: ios, pdf

Want to create complete report in pdf. i successfully draw text and images in PDF by using Apple documentation but i am unable to find any solution to create table in PDF with rowspan and colspan functionality, also if table size greater than pdf page size then it displays remaining table to the next page. Any solution,API or library which helped me for this Problem?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: So far i just create pdf in document directory and draw text and images in PDF. Now i am looking to draw table in PDF but couldn't find any solution for creating table in PDF with rowspan and colspan functionality.

Answer (score 0):

PDF has no builtin notion of tables. In fact, the only PDF primitives are Glyphs, Shapes and Images. If you want to generate a table, you have to stroke all the lines of the table yourself, using, for example, CGContextStrokePath (after you have built a path with the lines in the table).